# Installing / Using R Packages in Sublime Text 3

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I am trying to use the R function dmvnorm (found in the mvtnorm package) in Sublime Text 3. I installed it and ran my code in RStudio, so I know the code is fine. In sublime, I entered:

```
install.packages('mvtnorm',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library(mvtnorm)
```

It looked as though it worked, but when I ran my code it said:
Error: could not find function "dmvnorm"

I'm using a Mac and my hunch is this is somehow related to specifying the path in Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime REPL -> Settings - User. The current path displayed as part of the error reads:

```
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see there is much advantage of sublime over RStudio, although this is a personal choice. There are simply too many things in RStudio too good to skip, especially RMarkdown.

Comment: Are you sure the function is `dmvnorm` and not `pmvnorm`?

Comment: Thanks! I may end up switching back to R Studio, but I would prefer sublime if possible. And yes, the function is dmvnorm (it ran successfully in RStudio). I do get the same error using pmvnorm in Sublime as well, though.

Comment: If the package was installed already why install it again? Are you using R-Box in Sublime?

Comment: If you're working with Sublime, make sure you install [R-Box](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/R-Box) from Package Control. It has a bunch of tools to help fill in the gaps between Sublime and RStudio. Although I have to admit, as much as I love Sublime (see my profile for proof), RStudio is just *easy*. The inline help is great, the ability to go back through your plots, the ease of going through your packages and reading their documentation - it's great. I still use Sublime for some R stuff, but for heavy-duty coding I use RStudio.

Comment: Totally agree @MattDMo. If you're going to use Sublime and R, you're crazy not to use R-Box. But, also agree it's hard to beat RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time with this recently as well. I'm very new to R so I'm not sure this is the best answer, but to hold you off until someone gives a better one, did you include `library('package.name')` in the file (in sublime)? `require('package.name')` also works, but this appears not to be best practice for reasons described, e.g., [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-devel@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg00301.html).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, splittle! Indeed, I did not have that. I'm also new to R as I'm sure is now painfully obvious, but this is great to know -- thanks so much for your help!